# ajax crossdomain call

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, cross-domain

I am new to ajax

I am trying to get data from the url:

```
http://202.65.151.110:8080/ShreeMobileWeb/priceupdate" + "?d=" + "2%2C"+ "" + "%2C" + "150" +"%2C" + "100" +"%2C" +"N-A" +"%2C" +"N-A";
```

and my application is also on the same server *202.65.151.110*

but I still get error:

> Origin http://202.65.151.110 is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make an AJAX request to a different server (host *AND* port) as per the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). The solution is to use script injection or use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)

Answer (score 0):

do you use the same port? it is possible that it tries to access to  http://202.65.151.110:80, but not  http://202.65.151.110:8080 or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

The [origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) includes the port as well as the hostname and ip address.

Answer (score 0):

What everyone else said, but have a look at postMessage, which allows you to do cross-domain communication with JavaScript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage

Answer (score 0):

The Google Feed API can adapt any regular XML feed into a JSONP feed.

http://code.google.com/apis/feed/v1/

Answer (score 0):

You could use a proxy -> http://devtreats.blogspot.com/2011/01/cross-domain-ajax.html